# autossh does not kill ssh when link down

Tags: networking, ssh

I have started my autossh witt a poll time of 30 s:

```
AUTOSSH_POLL=30 AUTOSSH_LOGLEVEL=7 autossh -M 0 -f -S none -f -N -L localhost:34567:localhost:6543 user1@server1
```

And it is working fine:

```
Sep  5 12:26:44 serverA autossh[20935]: check on child 23084
Sep  5 12:26:44 serverA autossh[20935]: set alarm for 30 secs
```

But if I physically remove the network cable, meaning the tunnel can not be working anymore, autossh does not kill the ssh daemon. Why? I understand that autossh can not do anything if the link is down, but in my opinion it should try to do the following:

1. Verify the child ssh process (`check on child ...`)
2. Verify the far-end!!! (a ping-like operation through the tunnel)
3. Realize that the tunnel is down
4. Stop the ssh process
5. Try to create the tunnel again
6. Realize that it does not work, and setup a (exponentially increasing?) timer to check again soon

That is why I am running autossh: if something happens to the tunnel (be it a software or hardware problem), it should try to restart it. Instead, it is just waiting for the ssh process to die. Shouldn't it be trying to restart it, even if there is no hope of reestablishing the connection?

What kind of check is doing autossh? Just verify that the ssh is up and running? Is it not doing any kind of far-end check?

### Edit

As requested, I add the relevant part of the ssh config:

```
# (see http://aaroncrane.co.uk/2008/04/ssh_faster)
# The ServerAliveInterval tells SSH to send a keepalive message every 60 seconds while the connection is open;
#   that both helps poor-quality NAT routers understand that the NAT table entry for your connection should
#   be kept alive, and helps SSH detect when there’s a network problem between the server and client.
ServerAliveInterval 60
# The ServerAliveCountMax says that after 60 consecutive unanswered keepalive messages, the connection should
#   be dropped. At that point, AutoSSH should try to invoke a fresh SSH client. You can tweak those
#   specific values if you want, but they seem to work well for me.
ServerAliveCountMax 60

TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Comment: what about trying to reduce the timeout ?

Comment: We used autossh for a while, but it was way too unreliable on flaky connections, in particular when combined with port-forwardings. We now use OpenVPN and are very happy with it.

Comment: @NikolaidisFotis: the timeout is fine. It is ... timing out. But it does not do *the right thing* (imho) whenever the timeout kicks in, namely: **verifying the far-end**!

Comment: @NilsToedtmann: thanks, I'll give it a try. Is it easy to implement? Do you have any link to a good howto?

Comment: OpenVPN is pretty straightforward, we just 'apt-get install'ed it and started with the default configs for server or client, using `dev tun` in both and setting `remote` in the client config. The only annoying bit is to manage the certificates. We use the 'easy-rsa' CA that comes with OpenVPN. Once you have the certificates, the rest is easy.

Comment: could you send us the ssh configuration ?
especially the values for ClientAliveInterval and TCPKeepAlive

Comment: @NikolaidisFotis: added relevant part of ssh config

Comment: @NikolaidisFotis: which actually makes me think that `ServerAliveCountMax` is just too high?

Comment: 60 messages * 60 seconds between messages ... it will disconnect after an hour. why don't you try to reduce a bit the number ?

Comment: @NikolaidisFotis: sure, sure, I will try that. This is an ssh parameter, so the question remains: why is `autossh` relying on `ssh` to do the far-end check. Shouldn't it do the far-end check itself? What if ssh has a bug and it does never die? I guess `autossh` is not really aware of anything related to ssh: it seems to be doing just a simple process monitoring, and relying on the process being controlled to die whenever it must die.

Comment: I would say the name is confusing: this is not `autossh`, this is just a `keep-process-alive`. What is `ssh` specific about it? Just the fact that understands some command line parameters used by `ssh`?

Comment: if ssh fails (timeout), autossh will handle it. (Doing the way i told actually you force ssh to fail in your case). If you want to go the autossh way, you may want to have in mind ...

AUTOSSH_POLL
Specifies the connection poll time in seconds; default is 600 seconds. If the poll time is less than twice the network timeouts (default 15 seconds) the network timeouts will be adjusted downward to 1/2 the poll time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> But if I physically remove the network cable, meaning the tunnel can
> not be working anymore, autossh does not kill the ssh daemon. Why?

autossh runs on your client machine, so it cannot directly kill the ssh daemon process on the server.  However, you can specify a non-zero value for `ClientAliveInterval` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server (see `man sshd_config`) and restart the sshd service on the server to apply the config change.  Then in the event of a network disconnection, the ssh daemon process will be killed after `ClientAliveInterval * ClientAliveCountMax` seconds (but not by autossh).

Now, if you meant to ask *"Why doesn't autossh kill the ssh client process?"*, you have specified `-M 0`, which turns off monitoring.  From the autossh man page:

`Setting the monitor port to 0 turns the monitoring function off, and autossh will only restart ssh upon ssh's exit`.

Instead of using autossh to monitor the connection, you are waiting for ssh to exit after a timeout of `ServerAliveInterval * ServerAliveCountMax` seconds.  You have requested 60 server-alive checks before ssh exits, with a 60-second interval separating consecutive checks, so you will be waiting an hour before your ssh client exits.

You should also strongly consider using the `ExitOnForwardFailure` option on the client side (see `man ssh_config`), so that ssh will exit if it can't establish a tunnel, and then autossh can try to launch ssh again.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I indeed meant "client process", not server process.

Comment: And after re-reading the autossh man page now I remember why I set `-M 0`: it is not easy to use a monitoring port, and it is indirectly discouraged: *In many ways this may be a better solution than the monitoring port*